# Why jupyter notebook won't start?

Tags: bash, python, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupiter notebook via macOS console:

```
pip3 install notebook
```

but when trying to launch (jupyter notebook/Jupyter notebook) the console writes that the command was not found:

```
zsh: command not found: jupyter
```

how to fix it? what settings should I check?
macOS Monterey
python 3.9
.bash_profile contains:
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Comment: Try [brew install jupyter](https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/317) instead.  You can also use [pip-purge](https://github.com/ParthS007/pip-purge) to uninstall Jupyter then install it with `pip3 install jupyter jupyterlab`.  There are other solutions contained within the link.  I am left wondering what you have tried to solve your problem. Use pip-purge at your own risk I offer no warranties for it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic, it is recommended to use [conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html) [cheatsheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) to keep the system environment clean

create env

```bsh
conda create -n your_jupyter_env python pip jupyter --yes
```

remove env

```bsh
conda remove -n your_jupyter_env --all --yes
```